# redirect 301 to / if url contains index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a blog in laravel 5.8 and I want to redirect 301 to / it there is index.php in the url.

My .htaccess is this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle www + https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Redirect if index.php is in the URL
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have tried this approach:

```
    # Redirect if index.php is in the URL
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

but the problem is IF there is an url like this one that contains (?get_params)

```
htts://www.example.com/index.php?test
```

it will redirect 301 to /?test

How can I change the rule to redirect 301 to / (without any ? params) if the url contains index.php ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [QSD flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/flags.html) (Query String Discard) to redirect without passing the query string.

> When the requested URI contains a query string, and the target URI does not, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to copy that query string to the target URI. Using the [QSD] flag causes the query string to be discarded.

```
# Redirect if index.php is in the URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php /$1 [R=301,NE,L,QSD]
```

Comment: the same thing....?test stays in the url (/index.php?test -> /?test)

Comment: Updated, try using `QSD` flag

Comment: The trailing `/*.*` on the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ is superfluous. (The capturing `/*(.*)` in the question might have made sense - in order to capture trailing path-info - although that doesn't appear to have been necessary.)